# Safer way to remove salt from a decrypted key

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, salt

I have a decrypted key that is salted with random special characters (it's been changed): `J_a&3@000$0=f%4{4-f-1*1(1-d@0-3&e|0)1&987*5(b@123$1'1(4*0)1}c+f'59@d@8_6_c)4@1@c(3}` I need to remove all the special characters and return the unsalted version of it, for example, right now I'm using:

```
def remove_salt(decrypted_key):
    """ Remove salt from a decrypted key """
    invalid_chars = set(string.punctuation)
    return_key = []
    for c in decrypted_key:
        if c not in invalid_chars:
            return_key.append(c)
    return ''.join(return_key)
```

So it would look like this:

```
>>> remove_salt("J_a&3@000$0=f%4{4-f-1*1(1-d@0-3&e|0)1&987*5(b@123$1'1(4*0)1}c+f'59@d@8_6_c)4@1@c(3}")
'Ja30000f44f111d03e019875b12311401cf59d86c41c3'
>>>
```

Is there a safer way that I can remove the salt from the key without completely revealing what the salt is, what I mean is `string.punctuation` clearly states, that invalid characters are `!@#$ .. etc`. How can I remove this salt without completely revealing what my salt is?

Please note, the way this is salted was not my choice. I just need to get this thing unsalted without it being super noticeable as to what the salt is.

Comment: You could make `invalid_chars` a parameter instead. If this is still not what you're after then I would suggest having an external file for invalid characters that you read from and use. You could also condense your code down to `return ''.join(c for c in decrypted_key if c not in invalid_chars)`

Comment: Salts are not secret information, so you don't need to hide it. I suggest you look into standard encryption libraries.

Comment: Obscurity != security. This is not how salting works

Comment: Are you just doing this for fun, or do you intend to use this code in a serious application that needs proper security?

Comment: @PM2Ring Depending on what you consider serious. It's an API key, the salt was not my choice.

Comment: Ah, ok. Still, it does seem a little weird. I can't think of a significantly less obvious way to remove those punctuation chars. Sure, it'd be possible to generate a complicated looking expression that only returns `True` for a punctuation char, but any attacker who saw your code could just feed every char from `'\x00'` to `'\xff'` through the expression and see what happens.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, maybe I'm just being a little to over bearing, and a little bit paranoid. It's going to be fed as base64 anyways so even if they do find the decrypted key there's still a bunch of random trash thrown into the middle of it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am confused with your use of salt.  Salt is typically appended at the beginning or end of a password, and the result encrypted and stored.  Salt values themselves are stored in the clear, and are use mainly to make dictionary attacks more difficult.  So, when a user enters their password, you retrieve their designated salt from wherever you have stored it, append it to what they have entered, hash it with whatever password hash you have chosen, and check to see if the stored hash matches the provided hash.  Perhaps some clarification is in need - why are you trying to remove a salt that is embedded in the password?

Comment: Because this isn't a password it's an API key, the way it's salted was not my choice, I just need to figure out a way to get it unsalted without it being extremely noticeable